# Is there a way to easily record a phone conversation in-progress?

Tags: calls, call-recording

I do not own an Android device. I was thinking about getting one, and an important feature for me is the ability to record a phone conversation which is in progress - meaning, while I am in the middle of a conversation, I could touch a button which will save a two-sided audio recording of that conversation from the moment onward.

I am aware that recording a conversation I am participating in without notifying the other members is illegal in some places - I have already checked this and have verified that it is *completely legal* in my country.

Is there is such a functionality in Android, through core features or available applications?

**EDIT:**

- I prefer a solution which does not notify the other side of the recording, though it's not a must.
- I need a solution which works in any country.

Comment: FYI, you need to check with states here in the US for legality of recording conversations.

Comment: Just to add...Not all recordings of conversations are evil by the way. I use it to conduct telephone interviews with some of my clients, with their permission, and then write up notes from the recording afterwards.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are a couple of apps to try.  I use [Ultimate Voice Recorder](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ultimate-voice-recorder/com.fingertipaccess.ultimatevr) which costs $4.99 but works beautifully.  You can start recording in the middle of a call.

A quick search on [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com) brought up [Record My Call](http://www.appbrain.com/app/record-my-call/com.record.my.call) which is free.  I haven't used Record My Call so I can't comment on whether or not it can start in the middle of a call.

**Update:** Ultimate Voice Recorder does record both sides of the conversation.

Comment: Lots of the comments say that the Ultimate Voice recorder doesn't work? Quote: "Android system doesnt allow for recording the caller"

Comment: Most call-recorders that work on the phone itself - do not work on many devices. This is because of how the hardware is designed. 

The only solutions that work across all devices are the ones using an intermediately recording service. There are some such apps on iPhone, and currently only one for Android: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.scoompa.callrecorder.open. Disclosure: I am the developer of this app.

Comment: @Guy Is there a solution nowadays (2019) that work on standard Samsung phones (such as A3)? and that can record both sides, even if I'm the caller?

Answer (score 8):

[Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) can do this for you no problems. In fact, it's listed on the home page as a particular use case:

> make automatic recordings of what you say during phone calls to SD card

Comment: Only your side of the conversation, though, from that sentence.

Comment: I agree that sentence isn't clear - but Tasker definitely allows you to record both sides of the conversation. See the following for precise details:

http://tech.shantanugoel.com/2010/09/24/setup-call-recording-android-app-tasker-nexus-one.html

Comment: very cool! Though like other solutions here, this does use the speaker phone (it just turns it on automatically).

Comment: @Oak is this still true, does it require the speaker phone to be on? Can't we record both sides with Tasker and headphones?

Answer (score 7):

[Yes, it is possible to record phone calls using Google Voice](http://www.google.com/support/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115082) (but only calls that you receive).

Comment: Note that it does alert the other party that it is recording.

Comment: That does sound interesting, though limited; however it seems like an external service only available in the US at the moment, and I'm not in the US.

Comment: I don't believe that works when you turn off call announce though.

Answer (score 2):

Ditto Bryan on Google voice.

Another thing to try, download Voice Recorder from market. Turn on speakerphone during call with voice recorder running and recording in the background. That will at least record you, not sure if it will work for the other party, but might while on speakerphone.

Answer (score 1):

This is really an answer to [How can I record phone calls on Motorola Atrix 4G?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25731/how-can-i-record-phone-calls-on-motorola-atrix-4g) marked as a duplicate even though it's not but it also applies to here.

If you need a call recording feature you better **watch out and try before you buy**. Some device manufacturers will cripple the base software on their phones most likely due to reasons imposed by the BS hypocritical legislation in countries they operate. You can then install any call recording app you like and it may just not work because of that not because it's buggy (people don't know that and leave bad reviews).

The way they do it varies. Nokia used to inject bleeps in my Symbian phone, it was a pain to find software that would circumvent that. Motorola in their Android Atrix phone went step further and apparently modified the core libraries so that recording is not possible at all.

Sometimes there are ways around it if you are stuck with the current phone. For example, there is [Now Blast 2.3.5 ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1615689) available for the aforementioned Motorola Atrix on the [XDA developers webisite](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1615689) that originates from China. But still replacing the software [is not an easy task](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/index.php?title=Flashing_Guide_-_Android) if you are new to it. It costed me a night to learn the ropes, the lingo and fix this BS, and only this much long thanks to the support from other people who wrote the tools, guides etc. It also carriers the risk of making the phone unusable.

Here are my results:

[image: Motorola Atrix 4G]

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Nevermind.  [Found it and it has terrible reviews](http://www.appbrain.com/app/total-recall-call-recorder/com.killermobile.totalrecall.full).

[Total Recall](http://www.killermobile.com/en/applications/android/total-recall-android-%7C-call-recorder.html).  It's pricey ($10) and it doesn't appear to be in the app market but I like how it integrates with [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/about/trunk/items/totalrecall?lang=en&layout=default&source=mobile_page) and you can always sideload.

Comment: Outdated => "This app is currently not active on Google Play"

Answer (score 0):

I think this app has plenty of configurations to try in case it doesn't work:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boldbeast.recorder&hl=en

It also has options for rooted devices, in case all failed.