# How do I record all my phone calls?

Tags: call-recording

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to easily record a phone conversation in-progress?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/is-there-a-way-to-easily-record-a-phone-conversation-in-progress)

What I mean is, to record by default all incoming and outgoing phone call (both sides of the conversation), without having to do any manual action in every call.

Secondly, is this legal?

Comment: [This question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/is-there-a-way-to-easily-record-a-phone-conversation-in-progress) seems to cover pretty much the same ground: [Is there a way to easily record a conversation in progress?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/is-there-a-way-to-easily-record-a-phone-conversation-in-progress).  One of the recommended apps ([Ultimate Voice Recorder](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ultimate-voice-recorder/com.fingertipaccess.ultimatevr)) allows for recording all calls.

Comment: Matt H's comment covers the "how".  As for "Is it legal?"...

Comment: It depends on where you live.  In the US, it is going to vary by state.  11 states have "Two party consent" laws which means everyone involved in the call needs to know it's being recorded and consent.  The rest of the states (and DC) have "one party consent" laws so if you are recording your own calls you can be the one party that knows and consents and whoever you are talking to will never be the wiser.  Within these two laws there are also many variations that dictate how the recordings can be used for evidential purposes... basically, check the laws of your jurisdiction.