# How can I keep track of all types of contact interactions in one place?

Tags: logging, call-history

I'd like to record the interactions with different companies (e.g., the cable company) and document my interaction with them by recording the phone calls, uploading photos/pdfs of paperwork and set reminders...  Is this functionality possible in Android, and if so, how would I accomplish it?

Comment: App recommendations are offtopic.  Please see the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq) as well as [our discussion on shopping recommendations](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/164/shopping-recommendations).  If you were to ask *how* you can do this, my answer would be: Get one of the [apps to record your voice calls](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/is-there-a-way-to-easily-record-a-phone-conversation-in-progress) and put related calls, photos, etc. into a folder labelled "Cable company" or whatever.  Use a calendar for reminders.

Comment: This question has been flagged to be closed by several people and I agree with Matthew Read's comment above, however I'm interested in what you are trying to accomplish so I cleaned up you question so it can be salvaged. Please review the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq) and browse [the meta](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/) to get up to speed on what questions to ask and how to ask them.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be with **[Evernote](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.evernote)**.  You could organize it all sorts of different ways (eg. Organize companies by tag or by notebook... and a new note for each interaction...) and you can attach files (photos, pdf, voice memos...) to each note.  As far as recording the actual calls, as Matthew Read suggested, take a look at [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1699/137).

If you are looking for a more integrated approach that works with the current call log and calendar you could consider an app like [BizLog](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ar_apps.bizlogpro&feature=search_result) ($9).  It doesn't do everything you want but it gets you very close.  If this is more of why you are looking for I'd continue your search but use terms like CRM (contact relationship manager) and contact notes, contact log or contact management.