# Any voice recorder app for Nexus S?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, call-recording

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to easily record a phone conversation in-progress?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/is-there-a-way-to-easily-record-a-phone-conversation-in-progress)

I've seen Android call recording apps, but they don't support call recording on Nexus S.

Anyone know of an app that will work on the Nexus S?
Thanks

Comment: Don't any of the solutions offered in [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/is-there-a-way-to-easily-record-a-phone-conversation-in-progress) work for you?

Comment: Please remove the marked duplication, an app work on android doesn't means work on Nexus S due the hardware specification.

Answer (score 1):

["Working call Recorder"](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.scoompa.callrecorder.open) works on any android device, outgoing calls only.

It works by calling an intermediately calling service, which calls your other party with your caller-id. The recording is then emailed to your email box.
The recording is in high-quality, as it is done on the telephony level, and not through the mic.
The application only works for US and Canada.

Disclosure: I am the developer of this application.