# How do I increase audio sound on my app for recording phone calls?

Tags: audio, call-recording

I have an Echo phone and downloaded an app for recording phone calls, both received and made myself. When it records, my voice is very loud, but you can barely hear the other line unless it is on speaker phone. Is there a way of increasing there level without using speaker? I record phone interviews I do and it is much easier just using the headset and not using the speakerphone...cuts out parts of our conversation.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific. This is almost certainly something that would need to be controlled within the app, so we can't really help you if we don't even know which app you're using.

Comment: The app I currently use is Record My Call https://market.android.com/details?id=com.record.my.call&hl=en

Answer (score 3):

The recording works by using the microphone.  You're talking straight into the mic and thus are much louder than the sound that reaches the mic from the ear speaker.

You'll need to use an app that actually records the incoming call and not simply what it picks up from the mic.  Check out [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1699/1465), I believe it includes a couple such apps in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could also employ the services of [Google Voice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googlevoice&hl=en). It has an option to record phone calls, and you could also make them directly from your computer, which can be nifty.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution of this problem. I'm not sure why the call recordings cannot be recorded over phone calls, but only through the microphone of your smartphones, but I believe this one will help solve the problem. The app is called "Call Recorder - Cube ACR" by Cube Systems at Google Play.

I'm not sure what's the cause of these problems, but I found a solution. I share this app with the all of you and I believe it will help at least for now if they don't change any settings in future. I had problems with recording the phone calls and I couldn't hear the other side,  only my voice and if there was something heard it was very, very low as a volume because apps are working directly with the microphone of your smartphone and most of them  don't record when the loudspeaker is off. But this one does finally! Good luck!

Comment: Hello. Can you please link the app?

Answer (score 0):

settings -> additional settings -> clear speaker setting -> clear speaker toggle

Comment: My phone, a Samsung, does not have this setting, even through settings search. Is this a limited-use setting of your specific device manufacturer (which you do not name), and, is this suggestion appropriate to the Echo phone specifically asked about in the original post?