# Call Recorder not using microphone to record the other side

Tags: bluetooth, call-history, call-recording

Any Call Recorders that are digital - not using my microphone to listen to what is said in the other end?

What about recording calls over Bluetooth?

(It seems most most of these applications record what goes into my microphone, and listen to the other side through my microphone, often turning up the speaker to do that)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to easily record a phone conversation in-progress?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/is-there-a-way-to-easily-record-a-phone-conversation-in-progress)

Comment: No its not a duplicate because most of these apps are using the microphone

Comment: - I think they work by recording anything going into the mic, and they turn on the speakerphone, to listen to the other side.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking for. Are you looking for an app that only records one side of the conversation?

Comment: No, but the difficult thing is the other side.

Comment: Did a rewrite to stress the problem with existing apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Call Recorder - Boldbeast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boldbeast.recorder) does all the above - record via bluetooth and both sides of the conversation. You may want to check if your specific phone needs to be rooted.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that has to be enabled in the kernel. Some custom kernels do implement this, depending on your device.

Comment: This is the most correct answer here. With proper custom kernel support, you very much can have 2-way call recording, often abbreviated as 2WCR.

Answer (score 1):

I talked to the developer and mediarecorder_voice_call works if properly implemented in phone firmware, however many disable it out of fear (mostly in the US it seems).

Some (like skvalex's) rely on root/alsa/kernel support, which is not for the masses.

At the same time, even with proper voice_call support, bluetooth doesn't work because of android (or linux?) limitation.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=60323

Answer (score 1):

## Some Android phones have following issues:

- Can't record calls.
- Can record calls, but in recordings the sound of your side is very weak.
- Can record calls, but in recordings the sound of the other side is very weak.
- Can record calls, but during recording you can't hear the caller's voice.
- Can record calls, but during recording the caller can't hear your voice.
- Can record calls, but when you play back the recordings they sound like fast forwarding or fast rewinding.
- Some other issues maybe.

These issues are not caused by the call recorder, actually they are caused by the manufacturer intentionally - the manufacturer disabled the call recording feature of your phone. You should install a powerful call recorder that can fix this problem, for example this [Call Recorder](http://www.boldbeast.com/android/call_recorder.html).

## About bluetooth call recording problem

1. Some phones support bluetooth call recording perfectly, just install any call recorder and go.
2. The hardware of some phones don't support bluetooth call recording, for example Galaxy Note 2 GT-I7100, GT-7105, Galaxy S3 GT-I9300 etc that use the WM1811 audio chip. In this case all call recorders don't work.
3. The hardware of some phones support bluetooth call recording but the ROM doesn't support it, for example Galaxy Note3, Galaxy Note4, Galaxy S2, Galaxy S5 etc. In this case you should root your phone and install a call recorder that can fix this problem, for example Boldbeast Call Recorder, it can fix this problem for many phones.
4. Please note Galaxy phones have many variants, they are different from each other, for example Galaxy S3 GT-I9300 doesn't support bluetooth call recording, but Galaxy S3 SGH-I747, SCH-I535 may support it, or can be fixed.

## How manufacturers disable the call recording feature

Indeed almost all android phones' kernel support call recording perfectly, manufacturers usually disable the call recording feature out of the kernel (not in the kernel). If the recorder gets root access and it supports your phone it can fix the recording problem, no need to change the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to inform you: But that's a limitation in the system itself. Android simply doesn't allow this, and offers no API to record the "remote side" -- which is the reason it's hard to find any app doing so satisfactory. You will find several developer discussions on this topic, and it seems it turned out "being hard to work around that limitation" is a big euphemism.

Comment: I still find it bewildering how old Nokia phones can and has the option to record voice calls built-in to the phone whereas, something as advanced as an Android would fall short of such feature.

Comment: It's clearly not a hardware issue, and I agree with you: every old-fashioned analog fixed-line can record calls, so this can't be some legal issue either. To not spy on you, there could be some permission used (the permission system IMHO could also use some overhaul -- e.g. permission.INTERNET could be a bit more finegrained) -- so I really see no reason to completely block this. Unfortunately, I have no say in this area -- I'm not important enough to make Google listen...

Comment: We should start a petition then :)

Comment: Which one? Just take a look at all the tickets currently open on Androids bug tracker. There already have been plenty, and for years -- but they simply get closed with the argument "works as designed"...