# Record Speaker-Out Sound (not microphone)

Tags: audio-recording

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an app for android that will record sound coming from the speakers, like audacity does on the computer?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20230/is-there-an-app-for-android-that-will-record-sound-coming-from-the-speakers-lik)

Is there a way to record **sound output** in android. Some sort of app or any facility. There are few sound recorders which record Microphone **input**; but I just want to record the **output** from phone. For things like a segment of a FM radio broadcast, or a Text-To-Speech etc.. while Im wearing headphones.

Comment: This seems to be a frequent question. did you try the searchbox, or take a look at e.g. [Is there an app for android that will record sound coming from the speakers, like audacity does on the computer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20230/) There are also a lot of call-recorder questions which are related, e.g. [Call Recorder not using microphone to record the other side](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20658/).

Comment: Before I posted this, I read those. They doesnt have a proper answer (atleast to my case). Clearly this is some important thing for any android user. Keeping unanswered is not a solution. sort of sad 'cos something like Stackexchange couldnt make a contribution. Anyway, thanks @Izzy