# How can I record phone calls on Motorola Atrix 4G?

Tags: call-recording

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to easily record a phone conversation in-progress?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/is-there-a-way-to-easily-record-a-phone-conversation-in-progress)

I'm using a Moto Atrix 4G (MB860) running Android 2.3.6 bought from AT&T, and have tried a wide range of call recording apps but have yet to find one that actually works on my device. I notice that some apps explicitly explain that they don't work on Moto phones. Is this a hardware problem? Can I do anything to make it work?

I would like my phone to automatically record all incoming and outgoing calls, and save them in a common audio file type in the SD card or internal storage of the phone.

I've search the website, but the posts I found about call recording are *neither specific to Atrix nor Motorola*, which I believe are the key to the problem I currently have.

(Despite that I bought the phone from the U.S., I live in a country where call recording is perfectly legal to the best of my knowledge.)

Comment: See also [Is there a way to easily record a phone conversation in-progress?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/)

Comment: As the references SE article doesn't specifically answer the Motorola/Atrix question, I don't see how this should be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: While not easy to do it is possible, see my answer here: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/52432/40529

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer: No, you can't.

Longer variant: While you can recording your own voice, the system prevents you from recording the remote voice (the person you called or who is calling you). This already frustrated a lot of developers who tried to write some "answering machine" apps. So there seems to be no way without hacking the entire system...

Answer (score 3):

[Google Voice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googlevoice&hl=en) provides this functionality, if you install it and make calls through that number. They explain:

> To get started simply enable the call recording feature:
>
> Click the gear icon and select Settings [on [voice.google.com](http://voice.google.com)]. Click the Calls tab. Select
>   the checkbox next to Call Options. Once you've enabled it you can turn
>   it on during a call by pressing 4 at any time to record your incoming
>   calls. You can do it when you first accept a call, or any time after
>   it's started. To stop the recording, press 4 again or hang up.

NOTE: I believe this method stores the recorded calls online, but don't know if there is a way to save them to your device.