# How do I record calls on Viber, Skype, Whatsapp, Voxer, Google, Facebook, etc?

Tags: samsung, video-recording, call-recording, samsung-galaxy-mega-2, samsung-galaxy-s-6-edge+

There seem to be apps for [recording for local or international calls](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/is-there-a-way-to-easily-record-a-phone-conversation-in-progress) but none for **Internet calls**.

Some apps on the Google Play Store claim to be able to record calls on Viber or Skype. I even found some apps not in the play store. I tried some, but I'm not sure if they work. I haven't gotten around to testing any yet. Some reviews of the apps I found seem to be mixed. I don't feel like reinventing the wheel.

I have a second phone that I would use except that **sometimes the calls I make require earphones**.

If it matters, the phone I use for Viber, Skype, etc calls is a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge Plus, and my other phone is a Samsung Galaxy Mega.

Please don't bring up any stuff about legality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a screen recorder, or a sound recorder recording sound internally. I haven't tried it, but i found a few people recommending [this application from Google play.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nll.asr) It will record audio internally, and therefore i guess it will also record the sound from internet calls.

Comment: It doesn't work when I call on viber. Got other suggestions?

Comment: Listen via a I/O unit that lets you record the sound, since sound is going to come from the headphone jack, you can input that to the device and route it to a pair of headphones. Might be expensive, and is a rather not mobile solution.

Comment: That app doesn't work. It says error when it should record skype or wa.

Comment: 6 years later...not sure why i missed this but you said 'You could use a screen recorder, or a sound recorder recording sound internally.' yeah sounds like this could work. thanks!